# Validating images' URLs from an API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-resource

I get an array of images URLs from an API but some of them are broken. Is there a way to validate them to check if they're not broken before appending them to the DOM?

Comment: You can try to retrieve images via JavaScript, and test that the images come back without an error before appending them to the DOM. I'd have to see some of your code before recommending a particular way to do this, but if you look up AJAX and XMLHttpRequest you should get the basic idea.

Comment: Oh... another thing you can do is append the images no matter what, but set their CSS styling to "display: none" until you know the image has been validly loaded, and if you get an error, just delete the corresponding DOM node. You can use `img` `onload` and `onerror` events for this.

Comment: Do you mean just checking if the url is a valid url or if the url is actually redirecting to an image?

Answer (score 0):

???

```
function imgURL_checker (obj_URL_ChildNode_Arr)
    {
    var iterator=0, l=obj_URL_ChildNode_Arr.length,
        img=document.createElement ("img");

    function load ()
        {
        obj_URL_ChildNode_Arr[iterator].childNode.appendChild (img.cloneNode ());
        iterator++;
        next ();
        }

    function error ()
        {
        console.log ("URL not found: "+img.src);
        iterator++; 
        next ();
        }

    function next ()
        {
        if (iterator<l) img.src=obj_URL_ChildNode_Arr[iterator].url;
        else
            {
            console.log ("finished");

            //-- destroy
            img.removeEventListener ("load" ,load);
            img.removeEventListener ("error",error);
            img=null;
            }
        }

    img.addEventListener ("load",load);
    img.addEventListener ("error",error);
    next ();
    }

imgURL_checker ([{url:"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/02/10/42/kitties-304268__340.png",childNode:document.body},{url:"http://___",childNode:document.body},{url:"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/12/21/23/58/fox-576494__340.png",childNode:document.body}]);
```